# Scanner - Reading Strings, Ints, Doubles from a text File

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

im doing a simple sales report program which reads from a text file and assigns it to an array

The text file contains:

```
    Coke
    34 3.00 5.00
    Sprite
    18 2.89 4.30
    Fanta Mango
    21 3.35 5.99
    Orange Crush
    35 4.00 6.00
    Browns Cream Soda
    43 4.25 5.75
```

The problem arises, when I use the scanner to read each line and assigns it to the array.
My code looks like this:

```
while(in.hasNext()) {
            sodaBrand[sodaBrand.length - 1]= in.nextLine();
            numberOfBottles[numberOfBottles.length -1] = in.nextInt();
            costOfBottles[costOfBottles.length - 1] = in.nextDouble();
            retailCost[retailCost.length - 1] = in.nextDouble();
                
            }
```

As what I've expected, it gives me an input mismatch exception as it treats all the text from the file as strings.

Any ideas on where I could start to fix this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copied your file in my notepad. Let me add \n in your file for better explanation. **It it not how your file is. This is just for better clarity.**
*Here \n represents move to the next line.*

```
    Coke\n
    34 3.00 5.00\n
    Sprite\n
    18 2.89 4.30\n
    Fanta Mango\n
    21 3.35 5.99\n
    Orange Crush\n
    35 4.00 6.00\n
    Browns Cream Soda\n
    43 4.25 5.75
```

I noticed that when I copied it in my notepad. The last line of your file has no \n in the end.

I will also give the syntax of various methods you have used in your code. Visit here for more info on Scanner. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

```
 boolean hasNext()
 //Returns true if this scanner has another token in its input.

 int nextInt()
 //Scans the next token of the input as an int.

 double nextDouble()
 //Scans the next token of the input as a double.

 String nextLine()
 //Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was 
 //skipped.
```

Now lets see what happens at each line in your code.

Here is the code with comments.

```
    while(in.hasNext())                                 //returns true as Coke is available as a token for input
    {
        sodaBrand[sodaBrand.length - 1]= in.nextLine(); //reads Coke and moves the cursor to next line
        numberOfBottles[numberOfBottles.length -1] = in.nextInt(); //reads 34
        costOfBottles[costOfBottles.length - 1] = in.nextDouble(); //reads 3.00
        retailCost[retailCost.length - 1] = in.nextDouble();       //reads 5.00
    }
```

**Notice after last input of in.nextDouble() the cursor has not moved to the next line.**

Now this time when the condition is while is checked, this will happen,

```
    while(in.hasNext())  //returns true as it has Sprite as String available for input
```

But as I said **your cursor is still before \n in this line**

```
    34 3.00 5.00\n
```

What the next call to in.nextLine() will do is it will **return ""** and move the cursor to next line which is Sprite\n.

Now the next call to in.nextInt() causes InputMismatchException as it has Sprite available for input which is not an int.

Change your code to this.

```
    while(in.hasNext()) 
    {
        sodaBrand[sodaBrand.length - 1]= in.nextLine();
        numberOfBottles[numberOfBottles.length -1] = in.nextInt();
        costOfBottles[costOfBottles.length - 1] = in.nextDouble();
        retailCost[retailCost.length - 1] = in.nextDouble(); 
        in.nextLine();   //this will cause the scanner to return "" and move the control to the next line    
    }
```

Your code will still give NoSuchElementException after it has read all the lines. It does so because your text file does not have a \n in the last line.

Go to your file and move the cursor to the last line. You will see the last position of cursor is after 5.75. If you press down arrow, the cursor will not move.
This shows what that your file ends here. There is not enter or \n at the end.

Press enter and save the file. You will now see that the last cursor position is *in the next line after 5.75.* Now your file ends here. Your file now becomes.

```
Coke\n
34 3.00 5.00\n
Sprite\n
18 2.89 4.30\n
Fanta Mango\n
21 3.35 5.99\n
Orange Crush\n
35 4.00 6.00\n
Browns Cream Soda\n
43 4.25 5.75\n
```

After all this your code should work good.

One final piece of advice. I am a beginner myself and scanner is not as simple to work with as it looks. Its nextInt() next() nextLine() and various methods seem similar but they are not. This can lead to errors hard to debug. Try to use BufferedReader.

```
    43 4.25 5.75\n
```

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, After reading your answer, it helped me better understand how scanner works especially when I/O'ing text files.

Answer (score 1):

After the last line `retailCost[retailCost.length - 1] = in.nextDouble();`, there needs to be an additional `in.nextLine();`
Consider the sample text file below:

```
1234
word
```

That would be the same as:

```
1234.56\nword
```

where \n denotes a newline character. nextDouble() or any other Scanner method taking a number input will, will return the next available number. nextLine() returns all the data from the current position till the next line.
consider this code (where 'in' is a Scanner object with the above textfile as the input stream):

```
double a = sc.nextDouble(); //remaining input stream: \nword
String b = sc.nextLine(); //remaining input stream: word
String c = sc.nextLine();
```

As can be seen, in the second line, the scanner object immediately encounters a '\n' which signals the end of the line. Thus at the end of execution the values are:

```
a = 1234.56
b = ""
c = "word"
```